# PostgreSQL 10 not allowing remote connection

Tags: postgresql, connectivity, postgresql-10

I cant get a PostgreSQL 10 instance to allow remote connections.

The database is hosted on Ubuntu 18.04

`listen_addresses` has been set to both `'*'` and `'myactualip'` that needs to connect to the database.

`pg_hba.conf` has had IPV4 set to

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host all all myactualip/subnet md5
```

I still have no connection and get the usual "is x.x.x.x allowing tcp ip connections on port 5432".

The Postgres config file is listing 5432 as the listen port, `netstat -atn` shows the server listening on 5432.

firewall is disabled.

getenforce is disabled

I can ping the client computer.

The client computer that needs to connect also has firewall disabled.

I restart the Postgres service after every change, I've also tried restarting the VM multiple times to no avail.

Comment: `listen_addresses` should contain `*` or the IP address of the network interface, **not** the client IP address. What do you see in the PostgreSQL server log?

Comment: "_I can ping the client computer_" -- but what about a ping in the other direction? That's what's important.

Comment: connect with psql by using local socket and write `show listen_addresses;`

Comment: I can ping in the other direction just fine. listen_addresses contains "*"

Comment: I will check the log shortly.

Comment: @SahapAsci using show listen_addresses; I see that it still only showing local host. however my postgresql.conf file shows it as "*"

Comment: run this sql `alter system set listen_addresses to '*';` then restart the service

Comment: @SahapAsci thank you that worked! Is there a reason it wasn't reading my actual config file? I am a bit confused. I ran a show config_file; just to make sure I was editing the correct one and I was.

Comment: Just read the section [19.1.2. Parameter Interaction via the Configuration File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE) you will understand. The key word is `postgresql.auto.conf`